# Dynamically add/remove an element from another table with a toggle element (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an table with a several buttons, and I am having a hell of a time trying to figure out if I can remove the buttons I added to a separate table. I have looked for a long time for this and tried several different methods found here with no luck. I added a snippet.

So far I can remove the buttons in the table by clicking on them directly (thanks to rescources found here!)

My goal is simply that when a button is active, it is added to a table (array?)
When the button is toggled off, the button is also removed from the array.

Any help or hints would be great!

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach(button => button.onclick = toggle);
var counter = 0;

function toggle(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  button.classList.toggle('active');
  var addtolist = $('<button class="remove" value="' + (this) + '" data-id="' + counter + '">' + (this).textContent + '</button>');
  var containerDiv = $("<div />");

  containerDiv
    .append(addtolist);
  counter++;

  if (button.classList.contains('active')) {
    $('#selectedcourses').append(containerDiv);

  } else {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("*[data-id=" + id + "]").remove();         //This block doesn't do anything
    //$('#selectedcourses').find("*[data-id=" + id + "]").remove(); //neither does this
    //$('#selectedcourses').remove(); deletes everything and you cant add it back
  }
  $('.remove').click(function() {               //This block of delete code works...
    var id = $(this).data("id");                //I would like this to work when I deselect a button
    $("*[data-id=" + id + "]").remove();
  });

};
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: solid 2px #41403E;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #5fc0e3;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #ff00f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>2<sup>nd</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2<sup>nd</sup> year spring semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3<sup>rd</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3<sup>rd</sup> year spring semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>4<sup>th</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="13">Some class 13op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="selectedcourses">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="selectedcourses"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you have two jqueries loaded?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, I know the code is messy but I'm working on cleaning it up!

Comment: I just got around to it, was stuck in a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this much simpler version. I am using jQuery thoughout

```js
var counter = 0;

function toggle(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  if ($(this).is('.active')) { // only add if "on"
    counter++;
    $('<button class="remove" value="' + this.value + '" data-id="x' + counter + '">' + (this).textContent + '</button>').appendTo("#selectedcourses")
    $(this).attr("data-id", "x" + counter); // save the counter in the button clicked
  } else {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); // get the ID from the clicked button
    $(this).removeAttr("data-id");    // we do not need it anymore.
    $(".remove[data-id=" + id + "]").remove(); // remove the new button
  }
}

$(function() { // on page load
  $('#selectedcourses').on("click", ".remove", function(e) { // delegate the click in the container to all .remove buttons
    $(".btn[data-id="+$(this).attr("data-id")+"]").removeClass("active"); // deselect the main button
    $(this).remove(); // remove the clicked button
  });

  $(".btn").on("click", toggle); // clicking any button in the table
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: solid 2px #41403E;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #5fc0e3;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #ff00f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>2<sup>nd</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2<sup>nd</sup> year spring semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3<sup>rd</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3<sup>rd</sup> year spring semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>4<sup>th</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="13">Some class 13op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="selectedcourses">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="selectedcourses"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will remove button outside if you set not active,

and it will set button inside table not active if you click/remove button outside

```js
var counter = 0;
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach(button => button.setAttribute('data-buttonid', counter++));
buttons.forEach(button => button.onclick = toggle);

function toggle(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  button.classList.toggle('active');
  var buttonId = $(button).attr("data-buttonid");
  var addtolist = $('<button class="remove" value="' + this.value + '" data-id="' + buttonId + '">' + (this).textContent + '</button>');
  var containerDiv = $("<div />");
  containerDiv.append(addtolist);

  if (button.classList.contains('active')) {
    $('#selectedcourses').append(containerDiv);
  }
  else {
    $("button[data-id=" + buttonId + "]").remove();
  }
};

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  var bid = $(this).data('id')
  $("button[data-buttonid=" + bid + "]").toggleClass('active');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: solid 2px #41403E;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #5fc0e3;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #ff00f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>2<sup>nd</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>2<sup>nd</sup> year spring semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3<sup>rd</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>3<sup>rd</sup> year spring semester</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>4<sup>th</sup> year autumn semester</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="13">Some class 13op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="5">Some class 5op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="6">Some class 6op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="3">Some class 3op</button>
      <br>
      <button class="btn" value="4">Some class 4op</button>
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="selectedcourses">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="selectedcourses"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh it was really that easy! Thanks a lot! I spent a lot of hours over many days trying to figure this out, but that's how you learn!

Comment: Alright! I hope I accepted it now. This is my first stackoverflow post, let me know if everything looks okay.